# How to convert time from google places API in JAVA

Tags: java, time, google-places-api, unix-timestamp

I have a question. I've never did that before. So how I can to convert time in format, what Google Places Api is giving me, and to get hour of day from that?

[image: Result, what Google API is giving me]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses):

> `periods[]` is an array of opening periods covering seven days, starting from Sunday, in chronological order.
>   Each period contains:
>   `open` contains a pair of day and time objects describing when the place opens:
>
> > `day` a number from 0–6, corresponding to the days of the week, starting on Sunday. For example, 2 means Tuesday.
> >
> > `time` may contain a time of day in 24-hour hhmm format (values are in the range `0000`–`2359`). The time will be reported in the place’s timezone.
>
> `close` may contain a pair of `day` and `time` objects describing when the place closes. Note: If a place is always open, the close section will be missing from the response. Applications can rely on always-open being represented as an `open` period containing day with value `0` and time with value `0000`, and no `close`.

Based on this, it's up to you to parse the information and format it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to parse out JSON? If you're using Java, stick to Java. You have access to the actual objects. What's the point in using the client services API?

```
PlaceDetails place = PlacesApi.placeDetails(new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build(), "insert place id");
for (Period period : place.openingHours.periods)
{
    LocalTime time = period.open.time;
}
```